# How do I get value from this array?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I get all the customerId's within this array so I can add to a database?
My var dump looks like this: -

```
array (size=13)
0 => 
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[1]
  public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'ManagedCustomer' (length=15)
  public 'name' => string 'Butchers' (length=10)
  public 'login' => string 'james@gmail.co.uk' (length=22)
  public 'companyName' => null
  public 'customerId' => string '7100866198' (length=10)
  public 'canManageClients' => null
  public 'currencyCode' => null
  public 'dateTimeZone' => null
  public 'testAccount' => null
  public 'descriptiveName' => string 'miketest' (length=8)
1 => 
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[2]
  public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'ManagedCustomer' (length=15)
  public 'name' => string 'Vets' (length=5)
  public 'login' => string 'info@gmail.co.uk' (length=30)
  public 'companyName' => null
  public 'customerId' => string '5458013070' (length=10)
  public 'canManageClients' => null
  public 'currencyCode' => null
  public 'dateTimeZone' => null
  public 'testAccount' => null
  public 'descriptiveName' => string 'miketest' (length=8)
```

Have tried many things...

Comment: Tried many things... such as? Give us some example code so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: `$array[0]->name`, `$array[0]->__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name`, `$array[1]->canManageClients`, ...

Comment: Mr.Smith I have tried many like this echo $newclientidsarray[0]->name; but still nothing

Comment: Can you post the whole script?

Comment: Its intertwined with a google api, I went back a script and created a new array. foreach ($newclientidsarray as $key => $value) {
    $mynewarray[] = $newclientidsarray[$key]->customerId;
}
var_dump($mynewarray); This worked but did'nt after being base 64 encoded then unserialized...tried the same code on that page and it gave me NULLS....anyway thank you for your help.....

Comment: Have you loaded the class 'ManagedCustomer' somewhere? Your objects are coming up as `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` which suggests you haven't loaded the class creation code.

Comment: can you use `print_r` function and place the out put here? `print_r($your_array);`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your var_dump, you'll see that the array of objects created are of type `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`. This happens when PHP tries to create objects without having the class definitions available. In most cases, this can be fixed by including the file with the class `ManagedCustomer` at the top of your script using the standard `require_once('managedcustomer.php');` (or whatever the file name is) syntax.

If, for some reason, you can't load the class, you will need to investigate a few hacks: take a look at [Incomplete class object PHP](http://www.phpini.in/php/php-incomplete-class-object.html) or [PHP class casting](http://www.jasny.net/articles/a-dark-corner-of-php-class-casting/). You can also use `foreach` to access the variables.